# Why is this code not working? I am creating a Firefox extension but the code is not running. But if I paste the code into the console it works

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I make a firefox extension that get all the request url's and displays them. But the code only works if I paste it in the console.

when the extension loads it doesn't show any error, it seems like it just won't run

here is the full code

**xhrScript.js**

```
(function(){

    const proxiedOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function ( _, url) {
        this.__URL = url;
        return proxiedOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    const proxiedSend = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
        const { protocol, host } = window.location;
        // showing only when it paste in console
        console.log("full request url ", `${protocol}//${host}${this.__URL}`);
        return proxiedSend.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    };

})();

// this works all times
document.body.style.border = "7px solid blue";
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "XHR request urls",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "get all the request url's",

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["xhrScript.js"]
      }
    ]  
}
```

As you can see, in the last line is `document.body.style.border = "7px solid blue";`, this works fine every time. But the XMLHttpRequest `open` and `send` methods don't work. only works if I paste the code in the console.

if you want see an example, you can try copy and paste the `xhrScript.js` code in https://reactjs.org (it's a SPA, so it's easy to check what I want) in the devTools console, and see all the request.

I don't know why this code only runs when it is pasted in console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Content scripts run in an isolated JavaScript environment meaning that `window` and its contents are isolated from the page so when you modify it, you only modify the content script's version.

There are two solutions:

1. Firefox-specific.

   **Use `wrappedJSObject` and `exportFunction` to access the page context ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts)):**

   ```js
   const urls = new WeakMap();
   const origXhr = hookPagePrototype('XMLHttpRequest', {
     open(method, url) {
       urls.set(this, url);
       return origXhr.open.apply(this, arguments);
     },
     send() {
       console.log('Sending', new URL(urls.get(this), location).href);
       return origXhr.send.apply(this, arguments);
     },
   });

   function hookPagePrototype(protoName, funcs) {
     const proto = wrappedJSObject[protoName].prototype;
     const oldFuncs = {};
     for (const [name, fn] of Object.entries(funcs)) {
       oldFuncs[name] = exportFunction(proto[name], wrappedJSObject);
       proto[name] = exportFunction(fn, wrappedJSObject);
     }
     return oldFuncs;
   }
   ```
2. Chrome-compatible.

   **Use a DOM script to run the code in page context: [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).**

   It won't work on pages protected by a strict Content-Security-Policy (CSP) that prevents script execution so when writing an extension for Firefox we should use `wrappedJSObject` method instead.

Comment: Wow, it works, I'm really new to making browser extensions. This helps me a lot, thanks for share docs

Comment: To work with window.fetch, are we supposed to call hookPagePrototype this way: hookPagePrototype('window', { fetch( //...  ?

Comment: No, simply wrappedJSObject.fetch = exportFunction(yourFetchFunc).