# Listening for when a function is called in another JS file. (Firefox Addon / Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making a Firefox extension to skip a video when a video starts to be played in a web page. I need to listen for when the function to start the video is executed. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It depends on how and where that function is declared. The question is unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve). BTW maybe you can just listen to the standard [DOM `play` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event).

Comment: Here's the most boiled down version of my question. I need my extension JS file to listen for when a function is called in a web page JS file. The function that needs to be listened to is globally accessible.

Comment: You can access the global context of the page via [wrappedJSObject + exportFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) in Firefox, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817357).