# How would I go about detecting when a function is called?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to listen for when a function is called in a extension JS file. I know how to access objects inside web page JS files from extension JS files, thanks to user wOxxOm, but I'm still stumped on how to listen for function calls.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code or examples to help us understand your goal?

Comment: I wonder if you could use a proxy?

Comment: You simply redefine the function with your hook like [I've already shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817357) in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65651134/listening-for-when-a-function-is-called-in-another-js-file-firefox-addon-ext). Here's another [simpler example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62168202). You can probably find more by googling "wrappedJSObject exportFunction".

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh. I should probably stop working on no sleep. Thanks again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listening for when a function is called in another JS file. (Firefox Addon / Extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65651134/listening-for-when-a-function-is-called-in-another-js-file-firefox-addon-ext)