# Why UserScript's fetch intercept more requests than web-extension's fetch?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have this `UserScript` in `TamperMonkey` that I'd like to convert into an extension

```
let original_fetch = unsafeWindow.fetch;
unsafeWindow.fetch = async (url, init) => {
    let response = await original_fetch(url, init)
    let respo = response.clone();
    // console.log(url)
    if (url.includes("SomeString")) {
        respo.json().then((info) => {
            if (info.step === "lobby") {
                setTimeout(doSomething(info.data), 300);      
            }
        });
    }
    return response;
};
```

Within my extension, I injected this code with a `script` element:

```
let channel = "customChannel";
const oldFetch = window.fetch;

window.fetch = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        oldFetch
            .apply(this, arguments)
            .then(async (response) => {
                const json = await response.clone().json();

                const detail = {
                    json,
                    fetch: {
                        url: response.url,
                        status: response.status,
                    },
                };

                window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(channel, { detail }));

                resolve(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

Everything works fine except for the fact that the `UserScript` fetches more requests than the extension.

Can someone explain why and how can I fix this?

**EDIT: problem solved**

my problem was caused by bad timing, the script was injected after the call was made.

Changing `document.head.prepend(script);` to `document.documentElement.append(script);` made it works as intended.

NOTE: Loading the inject script with `script.src = ...` or `script.textContent = ...` hasn't made a difference (I decided to use `textContent` as suggested by wOxxOm)

Thanks everyone who answered and helped me

Comment: Use [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time).

Comment: userscript already has `document_start`, I set the extension's manifest to run at `document_start` but still doesn't work.. and userscript is working fine, my issue is with the web-extension

Comment: You need to reload the extension on `about:debugging` page after editing manifest.json. And you need to use textContent when creating the script element, not `src`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I missed that the code was injected using script element so the following answer relates to the difference with [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts) injection.

---

They are executing in different context/scope.

WebExtension content scripts are injected into `content` context.

Using `unsafeWindow` in a userscript will run the `fetch` in `page` context which is the same as webpage's own JavaScript (there are some difference between userscript mangers thought).

Without `unsafeWindow`, if you run `fetch` it will be somehow similar to WebExtension content script (again, there are some difference between userscript mangers).

In a WebExtension, if you want to run `fetch` in the `page` context, you can use `window.wrappedJSObject` e.g. `window.wrappedJSObject.fecth()`

Comment: looking into what you said, I've found that I should use window.top.fetch() ( new version of content.fetch() ) thanks you very much

Comment: The OP's code already runs in the correct page context as indicated in the question ("script element"). Judging by the OP's comment above the problem is caused by something else entirely.

Comment: sorry but I'm pretty new to all this, but using `window.top.fetch` instead of `window.fetch` seems to have solved my issues

Comment: If window.top.fetch helps it means that the issue was either 1) related to iframes on the site or 2) your `script` element was using `src` to load the code instead of textContent or 3) it was a timing issue due to document_start. In any case in Firefox it's best to use wrappedJSObject as indicated in the answer + exportFunction, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817357).

Comment: the website on which the extension run is a mess so 1) can be the problem, 2) `    script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("core/utils/injectFetch.js");` so I'd change it to textContent, as of 3) the extension has to work on both firefox and chrome but I'll take a look at that article

Comment: as of the article you sent, I'm using step 2 (injecting an external script) since I need chrome compatibility (as said above), but I can't find anything related to `textContent` instead of src