# script to overwrite fetch is not working using chrome.scripting.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, fetch-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to run a script to intercept fetch requests from background.js. I am using chrome.scripting.executeScript in order to run the script.

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
chrome.scripting
    .executeScript({
        target : {tabId : tab.id},
        files : [ "scr.js" ],
    })
    .then(() => console.log("script injected"));
})
```

In the script scr.js, I am trying to process the response which is not working. When I am running this same code from debug console, it runs perfectly fine.

```
const ofetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = async(...args) => {
var result = await ofetch(...args);
result
  .clone()
  .json()
  .then(body => console.log(body)); // intercept response here
return result;
};
alert("hi")
```

Note: `alert('hi')` for debugging which is running fine, but the fetch method is not overwritten. This whole code again runs fine from the console, including the fetch part.

Comment: Add `world: 'MAIN'`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/scripting/ExecutionWorld
File-Fox don't support world: 'MAIN'. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: Use wrappedJSObject, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817357).

Comment: Unlike Chrome in Firefox you can use webRequest.filterResponseData() to get response data directly from webRequest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData